# If anyone can offer advice on MS-Access SQL Full Outer Join

Tags: ms-access

I'm having a hard time with this, don't know if it's possible but seems like it should be.

So I have 2 tables, "INTERVIEW" and "INTERVIEWEE"

They both have 2 common columns:
INTERVIWEE_NUMBER & INTERVIEW_PROJECT

I'm trying to show a list of who has been interviewed and who needs to be interviewed still.

I populated the information I need in both tables with 2 separate queries.

the first:

```
SELECT INTERVIEW_NUMBER,INTERVIEW_LNAME,INTERVIEW_FNAME,INTERVIEWEE_PROJECT
FROM INTERVIEWEE
WHERE INTERVIEWEE_PROJECT IN ('LGBT','LGBTQ Civil Rights Movement');
```

and

```
SELECT INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER,INTERVIEW_PROJECT,INTERVIEW STATUS
FROM INTERVIEW
WHERE INTERVIEW_PROJECT IN ('LGBT','LGBTQ Civil Rights Movement') AND INTERVIEW_STATUS IN ('completed','processing');
```

I want to join the information from these two queries into two separate queries that show all of the "WHERE" information for who has been interviewed already and who hasn't.

I figured a Full Outer join and an Inner Join would do the trick. But I cant get my query correct

Comment: You only need an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT 
    INTERVIEW_NUMBER,
    INTERVIEW_LNAME,
    INTERVIEW_FNAME,
    INTERVIEWEE_PROJECT,
    INTERVIEW_STATUS,
    iif(INTERVIEW_STATUS IN ('completed','processing'), 1, 0) AS isInterviewed
FROM 
    INTERVIEWEE e INNER JOIN
    INTERVIEW w ON
    INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER = INTERVIEW_NUMBER AND
    INTERVIEWEE_PROJECT = INTERVIEWER_PROJECT
WHERE 
    INTERVIEWEE_PROJECT IN ('LGBT','LGBTQ Civil Rights Movement')
```

sry, missed the differences between your field names.  Also assuming you forgot the _ in INTERVIEW_STATUS:

```
SELECT INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER,INTERVIEW_PROJECT,INTERVIEW STATUS
FROM INTERVIEW
```

Comment: syntax error (missing operator) in query expression  'CASE WHEN INTERVIEW_STATUS IN ('completed','processing') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: syntax in Access and SQL Server and other dialects of SQL is different, need to specify

Comment: thanks Beth, I thought they were all the same... Grad student here trying to help out in the dept I'm working in and I haven't had much exposure to SQL yet. I guess the join operation isn't supported. Just got that error from your code. So maybe this isn't going to work.

Comment: have you tried creating a query using the UI instead of writing SQL?

Comment: I'll work on doing it that way. Just trying to help out a college who is giving a lecture tonight. Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
            create table #INTERVIEW(
            INTERVIWEE_NUMBER INT
            ,INTERVIEW_PROJECT NVARCHAR(50)
            ,INTERVIEW_STATUS NVARCHAR(50)
            ,NAME NVARCHAR(50)
            )

            create table #INTERVIEWEE(
            INTERVIWEE_NUMBER INT
            ,INTERVIEW_PROJECT NVARCHAR(50)

            )

            INSERT into  #INTERVIEW
            SELECT 1,'LGBT','COMPLETED','A'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2,'LGBTQ Civil Rights Movement','COMPLETED','B'

            INSERT into #INTERVIEWEE
            SELECT 1,'LGBT'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2,'LGBTQ Civil Rights Movement'

            SELECT 
                I.INTERVIWEE_NUMBER,
                NAME,
                I.INTERVIEW_PROJECT,
                INTERVIEW_STATUS,
                CASE WHEN INTERVIEW_STATUS IN ('completed','processing') 
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsInterviewed
            FROM 
                #INTERVIEWEE I INNER JOIN
                #INTERVIEW w ON
                I.INTERVIWEE_NUMBER = w.INTERVIWEE_NUMBER AND
                I.INTERVIEW_PROJECT = w.INTERVIEW_PROJECT
            WHERE 
                I.INTERVIEW_PROJECT IN ('LGBT','LGBTQ Civil Rights Movement')
```

Use this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6381b/1) and Convert it to your DB as per need.

Comment: Wc:)  Could you mark it as corrrect answer and upvote it ?

Comment: ProblemSolver I don't know why but I keep getting a Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement. Maybe cause I'm using Microsoft Access

Comment: he's not using SQL Server

Comment: Problemsolver, I'm using Microsoft Access, so I was getting an error from NVARCHAR so I changed it to TEXT as per w3school.com. However, I'm still getting a Syntax error on Create Table Statement

Answer (score 0):

Ok Completed

SELECT [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates].INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER AS [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates_INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER], [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates].INTERVIEWEE_LNAME, [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates].INTERVIEWEE_FNAME, [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates].INTERVIEWEE_PROJECT, [Completed/Processing LGBTQ  Interviews].INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER AS [Completed/Processing LGBTQ  Interviews_INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER], [Completed/Processing LGBTQ  Interviews].INTERVIEW_PROJECT, [Completed/Processing LGBTQ  Interviews].INTERVIEW_STATUS
FROM [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates] INNER JOIN [Completed/Processing LGBTQ  Interviews] ON [All LGBTQ Interview Candidates].[INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER] = [Completed/Processing LGBTQ  Interviews].[INTERVIEWEE_NUMBER];